# Histogram with frequency data

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to plot a histogram using MATHEMATICA from a 2 column data in which the 1st has the numbers increasing from the minimum to maximum having the same interval and the 2nd has the frequency. I calculated the interval as, interval = (max-min)/(number of Bins). The default Histogram[] works fine for a single column data without frequency calculated but now my data has frequency. Would you please help me on this?

Thank you very much;

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us your code.

Comment: dat = Import["data.dat"];       Histogram[dat]

Answer (score 1):

Generating some example data in the form you describe, you can plot it like so:

```
frequencydata = Tally@Sort[RandomInteger[9, 100]];
TableForm[frequencydata, TableHeadings -> {None, {"Value", "Frequency"}}]
```

[image]

```
Histogram[Flatten[Table[#1, {#2}] & @@@ frequencydata], {0, 10, 1}]
```

[image]